# how to use useMediaQuery in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

When using functions as components you have the ability to use the `useMediaQuery` hook from material-ui. However it no where shows you how to use this hook inside a class.

So I did some research and found out you can use it in a class by doing this:

```
import React from 'react';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';

const withMediaQuery = (...args) => Component => props => {
  const mediaQuery = useMediaQuery(...args);
  return <Component mediaQuery={mediaQuery} {...props} />;
};

export default withMediaQuery;
```

However when adding it to the class like this:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(withMediaQuery(Main));
```

It gives me this error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

I really need to use the media query because some variables are dependent on them. This is the render method of the class which I would like to use the media query for.

```
render() {

    const { classes, children } = this.props;

    const isDesktop = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.up('lg'), {
      defaultMatches: true,
    });

    const shouldOpenSidebar = isDesktop ? true : this.state.openSidebar;

    return (
      <div
        className={cc({
          [classes.root]: true,
          [classes.shiftContent]: isDesktop,
        })}>
        <Topbar
          onSidebarOpen={this.handleSidebarOpen}
        />
        <Sidebar
          onClose={this.handleSidebarClose}
          open={shouldOpenSidebar}
          variant={isDesktop ? 'persistent' : 'temporary'}
        />
        <main className={classes.content}>
          {children}
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I've already tried wrapping the component, but then I wouldn't be able to use the variables

Comment: Is there something special about your component that makes it difficult to convert from a class to a function component?

Comment: @RyanCogswell I just prefer to keep my code consistent since all my other components are also classes.

Comment: You will find that more and more library APIs will be exposed only as hooks. It seems like you're just creating more work for yourself by trying to keep consistent in that fashion rather than gradually moving towards function components.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure about that since I believe that classes will be the future of js. So I'd rather start using them so that I could easily add more complex things to classes such as abstraction and stuff. Thanks for your advice though!

Comment: Though they will continue to be supported, classes definitely are not the future of React components: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#classes-confuse-both-people-and-machines.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not supplying the `args` needed for `useMediaQuery`, so `Main` is passed as the `args`, and a function that expects the component is returned. When React tried to render (call the function), the return value is another function, which is not value as a react child.

Call the function - `withMediaQuery` and pass it the media queries, and then pass `Main` to the returned function.

Example:

```
export default withStyles(styles)(withMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)')(Main));
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of limiting yourself to only one media query a better withMediaQuery HOC could be

```
import React from 'react'
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery'

export const withMediaQuery = (queries = []) => Component => props => {
  const mediaProps = {}
  queries.forEach(q => {
    mediaProps[q[0]] = useMediaQuery(q[1])
  })
  return <Component {...mediaProps} {...props} />
}
```

This would allow you to pass in multiple queries as an array of arrays.  Each entry would be a prop name and then the query.

```
export default withStyles(styles)(withMediaQuery([
    ['isDesktop', theme => theme.breakpoints.up('lg'), {
      defaultMatches: true
    }]
  ]))
```

In your component you could then request the prop names directly in render

```
render() {

    const { classes, children, IsDesktop = false } = this.props;

    const shouldOpenSidebar = IsDesktop ? true : this.state.openSidebar;

    return (
      <div
        className={cc({
          [classes.root]: true,
          [classes.shiftContent]: isDesktop,
        })}>
        <Topbar
          onSidebarOpen={this.handleSidebarOpen}
        />
        <Sidebar
          onClose={this.handleSidebarClose}
          open={shouldOpenSidebar}
          variant={isDesktop ? 'persistent' : 'temporary'}
        />
        <main className={classes.content}>
          {children}
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: This approach introduces a linter error: `React Hook "useMediaQuery" cannot be called inside a callback.` It also chases the component into unnecessary rerenders.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai Sorry, I have not run across that error yet.  How do you find unnecessary rerenders?  I would love to fix it to be better.  I am using this in some apps now.

Comment: This works. It's an extension of the correct answer above to accept multiple arguments inside withMediaQuery and return different breakpoints inside props.