# How to use Material UI's 'useMediaQuery' with a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui, conditional-statements

Im trying to use Material UI's useMediaQuery to modify the styles of one of Material UI's component, which is the Button component. I am trying to remove the outline around the button when the screen shrinks. So I was trying to do this:

```
    const mediumScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));

 <Button
        name="discoverItems"
        variant={mediumScreen ? '' : 'outlined'}
        color="primary"
        size="small"
       >
        Shop Here
      </Button>
```

However, I am not using a functional component. Instead I am using a class component and  it is throwing error:

TypeError: (0 , _core.useMediaQuery) is not a function

Is there any way I can achieve the goal without turning it into a functional component? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use useMediaQuery in class component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672212/how-to-use-usemediaquery-in-class-component)

Comment: you cannot use hooks in class components, here is rules of hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 1):

There may be a [variety of ways MaterialUI supports this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672212/how-to-use-usemediaquery-in-class-component), but more generally you can always wrap a class component with a function component to get hooks passed into a class component you don't plan to convert to a function component at the moment.

For example, if you class component looked something like this originally:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Button name="discoverItems" color="primary" size="small">Shop Here</Button>
        );
    }
}
```

You could change that file to look like this:

```
export default function MyComponentWrapper({ ...rest }) {
    const mediumScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));
    return <MyComponent {...rest} mediumScreen={mediumScreen} />;
}

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const { mediumScreen } = this.props;
        return (
            <Button name="discoverItems" color="primary" size="small" variant={mediumScreen ? '' : 'outlined'}>Shop Here</Button>
        );
    }
}
```

The `{...rest}` parts just allow you to pass through any props. Any consumers of your original class component will not have to change. You're effectively asking that the `mediumScreen` be provided as a prop in your original class component and then providing a wrapping component that provides it.

This is sort of like an [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for hooks/class components.